# Initiating gameReady function on button click

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new at JS and I was watching a tutorial on how to create a simple memory game. I was confident enough to understand the logic behind the code to start making changes but perhaps I dont understand it as well as I thought i did.

Currently,the game starts and works when I click on the overlay text when the page reloads. I want to change this so the game ONLY starts when I click on the newly created "Start" button.

Ive tried the code below but it doesnt seem to be working. No error on my console.log.

Anyone able to point me at the right direction as to what the heck Im doing wrong? Any help appreciated. Thanks!

```
function gameReady() {
    let overlays = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("screen-overlay"));
    let cards = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("card"));
    let startButton = Array.from(document.getElementById("start"));
    let game = new SimpleMemoryGame (60, cards);

    overlays.forEach(overlay => {
        overlay.addEventListener("click",() =>{
            overlay.classList.remove("show-front");
            //game.startGame();
        });
    });
    cards.forEach(card =>{
        card.addEventListener("click" , () => {
            game.flip(card);
        });
    });

    startButton.forEach(start =>{
        startButton.addEventListener("click" , () => {
            game.startGame();
        });
    });
```

```js
class SimpleMemoryGame {
    constructor (time, cards) {
        this.cardsList = cards;
        this.time = time;
        this.timeLeft= time;
        this.timerElement = document.getElementById("time-left");
        
    }

    startGame (){
        this.cardToCheck = null;
        this.timeLeft = this.time;
        this.matches = []; 
        this.busy = true;
        setTimeout(()=> {
            this.shuffle(this.cardsList);
            this.timerStarted = this.startTimer();
            this.busy = false;
        },500);
        this.hideCards();
        this.timerElement.innerText = this.timeLeft;


    }

    //Goes through all the cards to remove the "show-front" class at the start of every game

    hideCards() {
        this.cardsList.forEach (card => {
        card.classList.remove("show-front");
    });

    }


    gameOver(){
        clearInterval(this.timerStarted);
        document.getElementById("game-over-screen").classList.add("show-front");

    }

    win (){
        clearInterval(this.timerStarted);
        document.getElementById("you-won").classList.add("show-front");
    }

    //Timer with if statement to trigger gameOver function when it is equal to 0. 
    //setInterval set at 1000 ms to replicate 1s countdown
    startTimer() {
            return setInterval(() => {
            this.timeLeft-=1 ;
            this.timerElement.innerHTML = this.timeLeft;
            if (this.timeLeft === 0) this.gameOver();

        },1000);
    }
    
    //Function to check whether card can be flipped by checking other functions as conditions with an if statement 
    flip(card) {
        if (this.cardIsFlippable(card)){
            card.classList.add("show-front");

            if(this.cardToCheck) {
                this.matchedCardChecker(card);
            } else {
              this.cardToCheck = card;
            }
        }

    }

    matchedCardChecker (card){

        if(this.getCardType(card) === this.getCardType(this.cardToCheck))
            this.cardMatches(card,this.cardToCheck);
        else
            this.cardDoesNotMatch (card,this.cardToCheck);

        this.cardToCheck = null;

    }

    cardMatches(card1,card2) {
        this.matches.push(card1);
        this.matches.push(card2);
        if (this.matches.length === this.cardsList.length)  this.win();
           

    }

    cardDoesNotMatch(card1,card2){
        this.busy = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
            card1.classList.remove("show-front");
            card2.classList.remove("show-front");
            this.busy= false;
        },1000
        )

    }

    getCardType(card){
        return card.getElementsByClassName("card-match")[0].src;
    }

    shuffle() {
        
        for(let i = this.cardsList.length -1; i>0; i--) {
            let randomise = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
            this.cardsList[randomise].style.order = i; 
            this.cardsList [i].style.order = randomise;
        }
    }
   // Function to check if the user can flip the card
   cardIsFlippable(card){ 
   //All statements need to return false in order for it to be true so they can flip the card
        return !this.busy && !this.matches.includes(card) && card !== this.cardToCheck;
    }

}

// Statement to check if the page has loaded 
if (document.readyState === "loading") {
    document.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded",gameReady());
} else {
    gameReady();
}


function gameReady() {
    let overlays = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("screen-overlay"));
    let cards = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("card"));
    let game = new SimpleMemoryGame (60, cards);
    
    overlays.forEach(overlay => {
        overlay.addEventListener("click",() =>{
            overlay.classList.remove("show-front");
            //game.startGame();
        });
    });
    cards.forEach(card =>{
        card.addEventListener("click" , () => {
            game.flip(card);
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: you need some HTML elements to manipulate through javascript

Comment: check `console log(startButton)` . I guess, it is blank array

Comment: Thanks for the answer Harish. Im getting a console error below. Unsure why it would return as "not a function". Would I need to create a separate function and not put this inside my gameReady function?

`script.js:149 Uncaught TypeError: startButton.addEventListener is not a function
        at script.js:149
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at gameReady (script.js:148)
        at script.js:126 `

Comment: @Lance, FYI you should add comment `under the answer` by @Harish. Or you should mention him with `@Harish` then only he will get `notification` about your comment.

Comment: Thanks @Karan. Pretty new to all this so apologies for all the mistakes.

Comment: @HarishSharma this actually worked . However, there is now a bug where if I pressed the start button without finishing the game first, the timer runs twice as fast and the counter goes to negative :/ . Thanks so much for your help though! Ill try figure this bug out!

Comment: Since you are new in JS so try figuring out by debugging code, that's how you will learn. : )

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById()` only returns a single node not an array of nodes.

So you can use `querySelectorAll` that allows you to specify to select multiple elements with the same ID or Class.

So change `startButton` assignment like below, And also replace `startButton.addEventListener` with `start.addEventListener`.

Add clearInterval in `startGame()` as described below. so when user starts game without finishing the game first then it will clear previous timer.

```
let startButton = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#start"));

startButton.forEach(start => {
    start.addEventListener("click" , () => {
        game.startGame();
    });
});

startGame() {
    this.cardToCheck = null;
    this.timeLeft = this.time;
    this.matches = []; 
    this.busy = true;
    setTimeout(()=> {
        this.shuffle(this.cardsList);
        // add clearInterval here so when user starts game without finishing the game first then it will clear previous timer.
        clearInterval(this.timerStarted);
        this.timerStarted = this.startTimer();
        this.busy = false;
    },500);
    this.hideCards();
    this.timerElement.innerText = this.timeLeft;
}
```